# Can you recommend how to manage package dependencies for apps hosted on shiny server?

Tags: r, shiny

I am hosting my Shiny apps via Shiny Server on AWS. The apps I am hosting depend on a package I am actively developing.

I want app1 to use a stable version of the package I am developing (i.e., be fixed to a certain Github release). But app2, I want to follow the latest updates (i.e., that I reinstall on the server every time I want to test something).

Usually, when I install the latest version of my package, this updates things globally, so app1 would be affected. But how could I have a fixed system environment for app1 and a different environment for app2 in this context? What is a good workflow to achieve this?

Comment: I'd recommend combining [golem](https://thinkr-open.github.io/golem/) with [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html). Unfortunately both are big topics in themselves, so you'll need to do your own homework to get started with them.

Comment: I'm surprised if there isn't a relatively straight forward way to achieve this. It seems like quite a simple, useful thing to be able to do.

Comment: To be fair you can probably do this just using renv. Alternatively, if you're installing to your server from github using `remotes` you could just point your dev version of the app at a development branch. Really there's no standard way to do this kind of thing, you've just got to find something that works for you.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. I think I'm close to achieving this with renv. "you could just point your dev version of the app at a development branch" - unfortunately not though, because that still happens at the global level i.e., yes you can install a particular dev branch, but not on a project/app-basis.

Comment: If you get it working with renv please update your question to show how you did it, I'd be keen to see how it turns out :)

Comment: Of course ! :-)

Comment: Answer posted :), it was pretty simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using adisarid's answer [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-server-renv/71879/5):

Using renv:

> log into the production server, get into the app's directory. Then run
> R, and use renv::restore and then renv::isolate.